# Button onclick, count the total price (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

This should be pretty simple, but I can't get it right. When I click the button with `onclick` event to a function, the total price won't show up on the input. What's wrong with my code?

```
<html>

<body>
    <h1>KASIR</h1>

    <form>
        -------<b>Nama Barang</b>----------------------------<b>Harga</b>--------
        <br>
        <input type=text> Rp.
        <input id="a" type=number>
        <br>
        <input type=text> Rp.
        <input id="b" type=number>
        <br>
        <input type=text> Rp.
        <input id="c" type=number>
        <br>
        <input type=text> Rp.
        <input id="d" type=number>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="fungsi()">Hitung!</button> <b>Total</b> Rp.
        <input id="total" type=number>
    </form>

    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
        var d = document.getElementById("d").value;

        var total = a + b + c + d;

        function fungsi() {
            document.getElementById("total").value = total;
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) You are getting the values *before* the user had any chance to enter them. Each  `x.value` returns an empty string. 2) You are performing string concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: 1.Do a `parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)` ...2)Move all the `document.get..` inside the function `fungsi`

Comment: where shoud I place the parseFloat? And if I move the document.get...,what should I write inside the function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works

```js
function fungsi() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("d").value;

   var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d);
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
 <h1>KASIR</h1>

<form>
  -------<b>Nama Barang</b>----------------------------<b>Harga</b>--------
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="a" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="b" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="c" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="d" type=number>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="fungsi()">Hitung!</button> <b>Total</b> Rp.
  <input id="total" type=number>
</form>
```

Comment: but there's still a problem.. I can run it to Mozilla, but not google chrome.. and even it works on mozilla, as I click the button, the total price is just show up very fast and then dissapear..why is it?

Answer (score 0):

Write Your function like this...

```
 function fungsi() {

    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("d").value;

    var total = a + b + c + d;
        document.getElementById("total").value = total;
    }
```

Thats right, first of all remove form tag as it will refresh the page second convert your variables from string to number like this..

```
       function fungsi(){
            var a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
            var b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
            var c = Number(document.getElementById("c").value);
            var d = Number(document.getElementById("d").value);

            var total = a + b + c + d;

            document.getElementById("total").value = total;

        }
```

Comment: Not quite. If the values where `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, the `1234` would be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the values inside the function, not when the script is first run.
Also, adding type="button" to the button stops it submitting the form.

ie:

```
function fungsi(){
            var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
          var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
          var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
          var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d").value);

            a = a ? a : 0;
            b = b ? b : 0;
            c = c ? c : 0;
            d = d ? d : 0;

          var total = a + b + c + d;
          document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```js
function fungsi() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
  var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("d").value);

  a = a ? a : 0;
  b = b ? b : 0;
  c = c ? c : 0;
  d = d ? d : 0;

  var total = a + b + c + d;
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
<form>
  -------<b>Nama Barang</b>----------------------------<b>Harga</b>------
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="a" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="b" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="c" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="d" type=number>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="fungsi()" type="button">Hitung!</button> <b>Total</b>Rp.
  <input id="total" type=number>
</form>
```

Comment: You created a demo but didn't notice that the total is incorrect?

Comment: values are string you should convert values (a,b,c,d) then it will work correctly.  var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d);

Comment: Too right you are, both of you, and the answer has been edited to work correctly. Even added a little NaN prevention.. which was causing me a headache.. enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your page are refreshing due to form and button that would be require to prevent.

below i have provided code.

```
  <form>
            <br>
            <input type=text> Rp.
            <input id="a" type=number>
            <br>
            <input type=text> Rp.
            <input id="b" type=number>
            <br>
            <input type=text> Rp.
            <input id="c" type=number>
            <br>
            <input type=text> Rp.
            <input id="d" type=number>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button id="buttonClick" >Hitung!</button> <b>Total</b> Rp.
            <input id="total" type="button"/>
        </form>

        <script>
            $("#buttonClick").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
                var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
                var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
                var d = document.getElementById("d").value;

                var total = a + b + c + d;

                document.getElementById("total").value = total;
                alert('jkhejhS');
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: What is this `$`? Also that still produces the wrong total.

Comment: @Grizly: The OP doesn't appear to be using jQuery though.

Comment: @HudoyoDanumurti can u let me know error which you are getting?

Comment: @HudoyoDanumurti: 

1. i have used jquery
2. at the start prevented page from refreshing.
3. changed type of button to button

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

1. The JavaScript is executed while the page loads. That means you are getting the `input` values *before* the user had a chance to enter them.

   `total`, `a`, `b`, etc. won't magically update their values when the user enters the values in the inputs. You have to retrieve the values when the button was clicked, i.e. inside the event handler. However, you can store a reference to the DOM elements themselves so that you do not have to look for them every time the button is pressed.

   For easy of use later on, I suggest to put them into an array:

   ```
   // Array of input elements
   var inputs = [
       document.getElementById("a"),
       document.getElementById("b").
       // ...
   ];
   var total = document.getElementById("total");

   function fungsi() {
       // here you get their values e.g.
       console.log(inputs[0].value);
       // but we will see a better way to compute the total
   }
   ```

   Instead of getting every input individually by ID, you can also use [**`document.querySelectorAll`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), to select all of them "at once":

   ```
   var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]'));
   ```

   The `[].slice.call` part is necessary to convert the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll` into an actual array.
2. `a + b + c + d` performs *string concatenation* instead of addition, because `.value` returns a **string**. I.e. if the inputs are `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, the value of `total` would be the string `"1234"` instead of the number `10`.

   You have to convert the values to numbers first. There various ways to do this. One of them is to pass the string value to the `Number` function.

   To sum the values we can use [**`.reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) if you put the DOM elements inside the array.

   Example:

   ```
   function fungsi() {
       var sum = inputs.reduce(function(sum, input) {
           return sum + Number(input.value);
       }, 0);
       total.value = sum;
   }
   ```
3. `<button>` elements are *submit* buttons by default, i.e. clicking the button will submit the form. This will cause the browser send a request to the target of the form and load that side. Since you did not provide a target, the browser will basically reload the page, so you won't see the changes made by JavaScript.

   You can disable this behavior by declaring the button as "dummy" button, using `type="button"`:

   ```
   <button type="button" onclick="fungsi()">Hitung!</button>
   ```

---

DEMO

```js
var inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]'));
var total = document.getElementById("total");

function fungsi() {
  var sum = inputs.reduce(function(sum, input) {
    return sum + Number(input.value);
  }, 0);
  total.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<h1>KASIR</h1>

<form>
  -------<b>Nama Barang</b>----------------------------<b>Harga</b>--------
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="a" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="b" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="c" type=number>
  <br>
  <input type=text>Rp.
  <input id="d" type=number>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="fungsi()">Hitung!</button> <b>Total</b> Rp.
  <input id="total" type=number>
</form>
```